# Xamarin.Forms content not showing after using Acticity.SetContentView

Tags: android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms

After using Android layout this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main), and LoadApplication(new App()), I could not see Xamarin.Forms MainPage.xaml. I tried to remove the Linear Layout, but it just removing items inside them, not the form itself. It seems like SetContentView blocking the Xamarin.Forms. So,

Here is **MainActivity.cs**:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Text.Method;
using Android.Widget;
using Auth0.OidcClient;
using IdentityModel.OidcClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace IndoFellowship.Droid {
    // Define App icon and name
    [Activity(
        Label = "Indo App",
        MainLauncher = true,
        Icon = "@drawable/icon",
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)
    ]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            // Showing layout that I set
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Do login
            // Some codes

            // Done processing on Android, I need to load Xamarin.Forms
            LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.mainLayoutID);
            mainLayout.RemoveAllViews();

            // Load App
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.axml** on Resources/values/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayoutID"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    // Some layout here..

</LinearLayout>
```

and my **App.xaml.cs** (Xamarin)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace IndoFellowship {
    public partial class App : Application {
        public static string AppName { get; set; }

        public App() {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }

        protected override void OnStart() {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep() {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume() {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs** (Xamarin)

```
using Auth0.OidcClient;
using IdentityModel.OidcClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Auth;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace IndoFellowship
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var browser = new WebView();

            browser.Source = "http://xamarin.com";

            Content = browser;
        }
    }
}
```

Over here I should seeing xamarin.com webView, but my Android just went blank. It seems like Xamarin.Forms not showing at all and I am still on Xamarin.Android. If I took SetContentView, I can see the forms rendered perfectly, but I could not process what I need to do on Android.

- What I need to do to properly load Xamarin Forms from MainActivity?
- Why layout not removed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution by using `StartActivity` instead of LoadApplication.

By creating a second activity:

**XamarinForms.cs** this activity load the app()

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace IndoFellowship.Droid {
    [Activity(Label = "XamarinForm")]
    public class XamarinForm : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.cs** instead of LoadApplication here, I am calling the second activity instead

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Text.Method;
using Android.Widget;
using Auth0.OidcClient;
using IdentityModel.OidcClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace IndoFellowship.Droid {
    // Define App icon and name
    [Activity(
        Label = "Indo App",
        MainLauncher = true,
        Icon = "@drawable/icon",
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)
    ]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            // Showing layout that I set
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Do login
            // Some codes

            // Done processing on Android, I need to load Xamarin.Forms
            LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.mainLayoutID);
            mainLayout.RemoveAllViews();

            // Load App
            StartActivity(typeof(XamarinForms));
        }
    }
}
```

May be this is not a best design since now I have two activities. Please let me know if you know better way to accomplish this. Thank you.